# how to run burn-in test for linux

Tags: linux, testing, hardware, fedora12

I have installed Fedora core 12 on my embedded pc, in that i have encountered few memory and I/O errors. But now i have reinstalled fedora 12 on my system. I just want to run the hardware test. Is there any "burnin test" procedures available for fedora 12 on text based command line or Graphical based softwares to test the whole hardware?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you intend with "burn in". If you want to make sure to test the entire range of RAM, for example, then [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) is pretty ideal. Same idea for a HD; do a full surface scan with various defect-checking tools.

For a sustained real-world load generator, source code compilation is a pretty common trick -- it loads of the CPU, RAM, and disk pretty well. Just download the SRPMs for some of the larger packages and rebuild them.

Also, standardized benchmarks are pretty common ways to generate load (and measure the result). [Phoronix](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/) makes some widely used benchmark suites.

As for GPU load gen, either a graphics benchmark, or perhaps even better yet, bitcoin mining. That'll have your machine at maximum safe temperature within minutes and can keep it there indefinitely. Assuming that's what you're after.

Comment: thanks for your concern. is there any single application either command line or graphical which could test all the peripherals ?